# Nested accordion - Add Anchor link and accordion inside an accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

When trying to create a nested accordion, is it possible to create an anchor link and accordion inside another accordion using jquery?

For example, in my code I have `<div>` for the accordion content and `<h3>` for accordion header.

Code is https://jsfiddle.net/vsf8kwko/6/

```
   <div id="outer-accordion">
     <h3>Outer Section </h3>
     <!-- I need to add anchor link under here and not an accordion. Is this possible -->
     <!--<div><li><a href="www.google.com">LINK</a></li></div>-->


    <!-- inner accordian -->    
   <div id="inner-accordion" >

     <h3>Inner Section </h3> //Accordion header
    <div> //Accordion content
        <p>Inner Mauris <a href="www.google.com">LINK</a>.</p>
    </div>


    </div>
    <!-- inner accordian --> 


</div>
```

Comment: What do you need? Your JSfiddle seems to work.

Comment: uncomment the line <div><li><a href="www.google.com">LINK</a></li></div>

Comment: You can refer to this https://codepen.io/brenden/pen/Kwbpyj

Comment: That example does not have nested accordion

Comment: I need something like https://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-accordion-header-act-as-a-link-to-a-page because my outer accordion consists of 1 anchor link and 1 inner accordion. So I dont know how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put both your `link` and your `inner-accordion` inside `li` tags. I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsf8kwko/9/). Check it now

```
<div id="outer-accordion">
     <h3>Outer Section </h3>
     <!-- I need to add anchor link here and not an accordion. Is this possible -->
     <ul>
       <li><a href="www.google.com">LINK</a></li>
       <li>
       <!-- inner accordian -->    
         <div id="inner-accordion" >

           <h3>Inner Section </h3>
          <div>
            <p>Inner Mauris <a href="www.google.com">LINK</a>.</p>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- inner accordian --> 
       </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```